# How to continually consume messages from Apache Pulsar?

Tags: scala, akka-stream, apache-pulsar

How do you continually consume messages from Apache Pulsar using Akka Streams and print each message?

Below is sample code I found from the [pulsar4s](https://github.com/sksamuel/pulsar4s) library. Instead of publishing the messages to another topic, how do you print the consumed messages?

```
val consumerFn = () => client.consumer(ConsumerConfig(Seq(intopic), Subscription("mysub")))
val producerFn = () => client.producer(ProducerConfig(outtopic))

val control = source(consumerFn, Some(MessageId.earliest))
                .map { consumerMessage => ProducerMessage(consumerMessage.data) }
                .to(sink(producerFn)).run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `Sink.foreach(println))`

For example

```
source(consumerFn, Some(MessageId.earliest))
.runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
```

Comment: On trying above solution i got no implicits found for parameter materializer. then added below code ```
    source(consumerFn, Some(MessageId.earliest))
      .runWith(Sink.foreach[String](println))
```
now getting type mismatch. Can you please help me by providing a small code snippet to consume message. from pulsar using scala